# selectively explode lists from Dataframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

What is the best way to `explode` a comma separated column based on specific conditions?
I have some data in the following format:

| ID | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a100,a101,b100,c100 |
| 2 | a105,b100 |
| 3 | b101, c104 |

what I want to achieve is to:

1. grab all the elements in col1 column that are starting with **a** and explode them.
2. If one record has none a### elements in col1 then I would still like to include them in the end results with a default value.
3. All the a### elements are in the beginning of the list, that means that once I read an element that starts with anything different than **a**, then I don't have to parse the rest list.

Basically the wished outcome shall look like:

| ID | element |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a100 |
| 1 | a101 |
| 2 | a105 |
| 3 | default |

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame (df_1):

```
+---+-------------------+
|ID |col1               |
+---+-------------------+
|1  |a100,a101,b100,c100|
|2  |a105,b100          |
|3  |b101,c104          |
+---+-------------------+
```

1. Use RDD functions to iterate through the `col1` elements and filter accordingly

```
rdd = df_1.rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], [value for value in row[1].split(",") if value[0].startswith("a")]))
```

2. convert RDD to DataFrame

```
df_2 = rdd.toDF(df_1.columns)
```

3. Use `explode_outer()` which returns a new row for each element in the given array and returns `null` for empty or null values

```
df_3 = df_2.withColumn("col1", explode_outer("col1"))
```

4. Replace the column `col1` null values with *'default'* string

```
df_3.fillna({"col1":"default"}).show()
```

***Output***

```
+---+-------+
| ID|   col1|
+---+-------+
|  1|   a100|
|  1|   a101|
|  2|   a105|
|  3|default|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: sorry that might be a dumb question but I cannot understand where the split/next row check is applied in col1. my actual problem has a lot more columns so I would like it to be more targeted

Comment: What do you mean by next row check

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame (`df_1`):  (*warning I didn't run this code but I think you get the idea of what I"m suggesting from the code itself*)

I would explode and filter:

```
df_result = df_1.select(\
  "ID", 
  F.explode(\
   F.split(F.col("col1"), ",")
  ).alias("col1_exploded"))\
  .filter(F.col("col1_exploded").startsWith("a"))\
  .join( df_1, [ "ID" ], "left" )\
  .select( F.col("ID"), F.coalesce( col("col1_exploded"), F.lit("default") ).alias("col1") )
```

I suggest using this over an rdd `map` function as it can be optimized by the compiler unlike a 'udf' which is what calling 'map' on an RDD actually creates. (The `map` function needs to be passed back to the python runtime for execution then the results passed back to SPARK runtime, where as the version above (Without map) is computed completely in the SPARK runtime without needing to pass back and forth to the python runtime.)

However even though it runs faster, if you feel the 'map' version is more readable, maintainable and you don't need speed, then by all means use the approach suggested by @arudsekaberne.  Just be aware of your choice and know that there is another approach should you need more speed.